# SSIS XML Config File Location

Tags: sql-server, xml, configuration, ssis

I'm planning to use XML configuration files to run SSIS jobs on both development and production servers.  I'll be using the SQL Server to store the SSIS packages.  I'm wondering if there's a standard place to store the XML files.  There's no need to create a project folder for the packages since they'll be stored in the database.  So is it better to store the XML files in a central location like C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS ?

Comment: I'm very interested in this question.  I've taken over some packages where .xsd schemas on the c: drive are referenced.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you never put data on the C: drive.  Ever.  Even config data.  As an admin this used to drive me nuts.  I've wasted hours rebuilding servers because some process went ape and filled the C: drive with crap.  I'm surprised that a developer would have access to a C: drive.